# from two tables make a new one

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have two tables both of them has linestring geometry. I try to make a new one which contain the first one and from the second take only the decimal v when the linestring of the first table touch a linestring of the second.

```
CREATE TABLE Three AS(
SELECT st_astext(r.geom),e."v" FROM r , e WHERE ST_Touches(e.geom, ST_Transform(r.geom,4326)));
```

But i am not take an error or a result , the geom of r is in another srid than the 4326 which is the e and i transform it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is, but just to check further, you might try some checks like:

```
SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM r; 
SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM e; 
SELECT ST_Touches(e.geom , ST_Transform(r.geom, 4326)) FROM e,r;
```

Also note that ST_Touches() returns true **only** if lines cross exactly at a vertex or node. For example:

```
SELECT ST_Touches('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 2)'::geometry, 'LINESTRING(0 2, 2 0)'::geometry);
```

returns false. You might be wanting ST_Crosses(), or ST_Intersects().

Comment: I try `SELECT st_astext(r.geom),e."E" FROM  r ,  e WHERE ST_Crosses(and ST_Intersect )(ST_StartPoint(ST_Transform(r.geom,4326)),e.geom);`
but i dont take again results i take a empty table

Comment: Can you post the outputs of the first two queries in the answer above? (just to be sure what CRS yuor data are in)?